# Lebesgue Measure of Closed and Open Sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I am given the definition of the Lebesgue Measure:

Lebesgue Measure $\mathcal P$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B[0,1]$:
$\mathcal P[[a,b]] = b - a$ for all $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$

The definition states the following: $\mathcal P[[a,a]] = a - a = 0$. Therefore $\mathcal P[(a,b)] = \mathcal P[[a,b]] = b - a$

Why can the last statement be postulated? The Lebesgue Measure of the open interval should be infinitesimal smaller than the one of the closed interval. Where do I make a mistake in this thinking?

Comment: Why do you think it's false? It's not supposed to be "infinitesimally smaller" - that doesn't even make sense

Comment: @Lorago I think it's smaller because $a$ and $b$ are not included in the open set but are included in the closed set. As the Lebesgue measure given can be seen as "length", the Lebesgue measure of the open set must be slightly smaller

Comment: Intuitively, one could say that $$\mathcal{P}\left[[a,b]\right]=\mathcal{P}\left[(a,b)\right]-\mathcal{P}\left[\{a\}\right]-\mathcal{P}\left[\{b\}\right]$$
but we know that the Lebesgue measure of a singleton is $0$.

Comment: @asdf1234 It is generally understood that a singleton set has length 0, so just missing two endpoints does not change the length, so to speak. But you certainly could say that feels unsatisfactory, given that we’re basically “discarding” something when defining “length”. Unfortunately there isn’t a notion of infinitesimal numbers in the real numbers, so that couldn’t be captured in the usual definition of a measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidGao
Your answer was very helpful & exactly what I was looking for